# Notify Angular 2 component of change from a service

Tags: authentication, angular, typescript

Using Angular 2, I have an AuthService that handles authentication. I'm trying to figure out the best way to notify other components when a user has logged in/out, but am unsure of the right way to handle this scenario. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: have method that returns an observable or a promise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to use **BehaviorSubject**.

```
class AuthService {

private _isLoggedIn:Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  getUser() {
      return !!localStorage.getItem('user');     
  };

  isLoggedIn() {
    this.getUser() && this._isLoggedIn.next(true);
    !this.getUser() && this._isLoggedIn.next(false);
    return this._isLoggedIn.asObservable();
  }
}
```

// In your component

```
class NavComponent {
    constructor(private AuthService: AuthService) {
        this.AuthService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(status => this.isLoggedIn = status);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have duplicate definitions of `isLoggedIn`.

Comment: One is the component and one is the service

Comment: `isLoggedIn` is both a field and a method in `AuthService`.